# Jquery only click once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable a li click event after it has clicked the first time. Essentially to stop the array data being doubled. The click is working fine for each time. My current method doesn't appear to be working. I also need to disable the other li's from being clicked once the first one has :)

Thanks

JS code is:

```
$('#eventType ul li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    answers.push(value);
    // Below isn't working
    $(this).click(function() {
        return false;
    });
    console.log(answers);
});
```

Comment: You can use jQuery `one` method: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is just JavaScript so you can easily add behaviors that you want

```
// basic jQuery plugin boilerplate
$.fn.once = function once(eventType, f) {
  // this = the selected elements
  return this.each(idx, elem) {
    // create reference to jQuery-wrapped elem
    var $elem = $(elem);
    // add event listener for eventType
    $elem.on(eventType, function(event) {
      // call the event handler
      return f(event);
      // remove the event handler
      $elem.off(eventType, f);
    });
  });
};
```

Usage would look like this

```
$('#eventType ul li').once('click', function(event) {
  console.log("you will only see this once");
});
```

However, this is obviously a common need so it exists in jQuery already. It's called [$.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/). As APIs grow, you may not know about the existence of such procedures. This answer exists to show you that you can use your brain to program the things that you want or that might be missing from a particular library. This lessens your dependence on the creator's of the lib to introduce the functionality you need.

---

**EDIT**

In a comment, you ask if the event handler can be disabled for all other LI elements after the first LI is clicked. The trouble here is that jQuery uses **implicit iteration**, which means that when you call `$('li').on('click', ...)`, jQuery will bind an `onclick` event handler for *each* LI.

A better solution to this problem would be to use jQuery's [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```js
// only fire event handler for the first LI clicked
$('ul').one('click', 'li', function(event) {
  console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

This will delegate the event listener to the children LI, but once one of the LI is clicked, the event handler will be removed (because we delegated using the `$.one` procedure).

Try clicking one LI, you will see a message in the console. When you click the second LI, nothing will happen because the event handler was removed.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know .one existed :).

Comment: @JesseC, and that's exactly my point. You can add functionality that you need when you need it. If you later find out that the procedure exists, you can replace your implementation with a call to the library's procedure, if you wish.

Answer (score 12):

you need to use `one`:

```
$('#eventType ul li').one('click',function(){
    //your code here
});
```

this event will be fired only once

**UPDATE**

you can do that using `$.off()`

```
$('#eventType ul li').one('click',function(){
  //your code here
  $('#eventType ul li').off('click');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. this solution works. is there a way to prevent the other li items from being clicked also?

Comment: you need to give your li a unique id, or something that you can specify it in the selector (e.g. index, special attribute, ...)

Comment: @JesseC I updated my answer to show you how to add a single-use event handler for multiple elements.

Comment: @AminJafari, your edit is identical in functionality to your first code.

Comment: yeah I just got it, undoing it

Answer (score 0):

```
var used = false;
$('#eventType ul li').click(function(e) {
  if (used == false) {
    used = true;
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    answers.push(value);
    console.log(answers);
  }
});
```

the way you did it was just adding another on click handler, not removing or overriding the old ond.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS classes; add the class 'disabled' to elements you don't need, and avoid adding elements that have the classe 'disabled'.

https://plnkr.co/edit/6aloNPETHGxfiP5oYZ9f?p=preview

```
    $('ul li').click(function(e) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
          var value = $(this).text();
          answers.push(value);
          $('li').addClass('disabled');
        }

        console.log(answers);
    });
```